# Get the action name of referer url (previous url) in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I've the referer url which is from $this->referer() is given below

`http://localhost/project/users/login`

And i want to get action of the referer url (previous url),

How can i get it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get the referer full base url, we use `$this->referer()`, if you parse `Router::parse($this->referer());` we get an empty array

but to restrict referring urls to local server, you've to use pass additional param like below

`$refer_url = $this->referer('/', true); // you get like "/project/users/login"`

Now if you parse the above returned value
`$parse_url_params = Router::parse($refer_url);`

you'll get the details of **Controller, Action & Plugin**

Here are the details:

```
Array ( 
    [plugin] =>  
    [controller] => users 
    [action] => login 
    [named] => Array () 
    [pass] => Array ( ) 
)
```

Comment: can i use $refer_url = $this->referer('/', true);  in production and local enviroment and get the same results ?  or will i get diferent results in both enviroments ?

Comment: hi, i got the same question, would we get the different results for local and production environment using $refer_url = $this->referer('/', true)?

Answer (score 2):

In cakephp 3, try this

```
 $this->request->referer();
```